# Add a custom tooltip to Mapoverlay in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

My wp8 app dynamically creat a map object and add the coordinations with MapOverlays. I need a tooltip for each location to be able to show the place name and navigate to a web page by taping on the text or button inside the toolip. There are some examples with static pushpin but i cannot find an example which has done this with mapoverlay. Would you please help me.

```
Image pinIMG2 = new Image();
                pinIMG2.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("pin2.png", UriKind.Relative));
                pinIMG2.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None;

    MapOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                    myLocationOverlay.Content = pinIMG2;
                    myLocationOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                    myLocationOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(57.724611, 12.938945);

    MapLayer myLocationLayer = new MapLayer();
    myLocationLayer.Add(myLocationOverlay);
    MyMap.Layers.Add(myLocationLayer);
```